# Grouping files with name and move them to respective directories using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to group files on the basis of names (first few letters before _) and moving them to separate directories (create new if doesn't exist) using awk.

Test data can be created using commands:

```
echo "1" > 123_20190911_110011.txt
echo "2" > 123_20190911_110012.txt
echo "0" > 123_20190910_110010.txt
echo "1" > 1234_20190911_110011.txt
echo "2" > 1234_20190911_110012.txt
echo "0" > 1234_20190910_110010.txt
```

The output of ls -ltr is :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 vipin vipin 2 Sep 11 23:17 123_20190911_110011.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 vipin vipin 2 Sep 11 23:17 123_20190911_110012.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 vipin vipin 2 Sep 11 23:17 123_20190910_110010.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 vipin vipin 2 Sep 11 23:17 1234_20190911_110011.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 vipin vipin 2 Sep 11 23:17 1234_20190911_110012.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 vipin vipin 2 Sep 11 23:17 1234_20190910_110010.txt
```

In this case, I am expecting 2 directories 123 and 1234 and files to move into directories like:

```
Dir 123 has files
 123_20190911_110011.txt
 123_20190911_110012.txt
 123_20190910_110010.txt
Dir 1234 has files
 1234_20190911_110011.txt
 1234_20190911_110012.txt
 1234_20190910_110010.txt
```

Below code is not working. Not even creating the directory and doesn't show any error.

```
for i in `ls -p | grep -v /` ## to list only files
do 
echo $i | awk -F'_' '{mkdir -p $1; cp $i $1}'
done
```

Able to create directories using the below command, but how can I add move command in this?

```
for i in `ls -p | grep -v / `; do echo $i | awk -F'_' '{print $1; dir= $1}' | xargs mkdir -p ; done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be doing `mv` or `cp` inside `awk`. The following works:

```bsh
for i in * ; do
  [ -f "$i" ] || continue
  dir_name="$(echo $i | awk -F'_' '{print $1}')"
  mkdir -p -- "$dir_name"
  cp -- "$i" "$dir_name"
done
```

---

However, instead of `awk`, you could use the `%` operator in bash to remove everything after the first underscore to get the directory name.

```bsh
for i in * ; do
  [ -f "$i" ] || continue
  dir_name="${i%%_*}"
  mkdir -p -- "$dir_name"
  cp -- "$i" "$dir_name"
done
```

(use `mv` instead of `cp` if you want to move)

Comment: You also shouldn't parse the output of `ls`. Simple wildcards and `test -f` would do.

Comment: @JeffSchaller  you mean ‘find . -type f’ ?

Comment: Good point. I think @JeffSchaller was hinting at adding a check inside the for loop. I updated the answer to use `find . -type f` though

Comment: No; I meant: `for i in *.txt; do if [ -f "$i" ] ...`. Looping over `find's` output is equally dangerous.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant -- you're adding a check "inside" the for loop. Could you also explain why is looping over the output of `find` dangerous in this case? Isn't "looping over names and then checking" equivalent to "looping over checked filenames"?

Comment: If any filename contains whitespace (anything in `$IFS`) it will be split; `touch "123_20 space.txt"` to see an example.

Comment: Good catch! Thank you :)

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Put all filenames in samplefile and follow the below steps

```
#step1 it creates directory

awk -F "_" '{print $1}' samplefile | awk '{if (!seen [$1]++)print "mkdir" " " $0}'| sh

#step2: moves file to respective directory

 for i in `awk -F "_" '{print $1}' samplefile | sort -u` ; do sed -n '/^'$i'_/p' samplefile | awk -v i="$i" '{print "mv" " " $1 " " i}'|sh ; done
```